# What is different between buy and Restore in in-app purchase android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I used this library for  in-app purchase in my android project
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Everything for payment is works, but problem is how to real restore ,because when user wants buy again this product

my question is how to know user bought or restore product

Answer (score 0):

`Buy` let the user buy a product. `Restore` retrieves all the purchased products, all the products currently owned by the user for that application

`Restore` is a very cheap call to the local Google Play authority process and it should be called at startup to enable or disable features depending on the presence of a given product